# In Google Chrome extension, how can I perform some cleanup with page_action?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension for Google Chrome which is supposed to be used only with selected pages, hence it uses [page_action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/user_interface#page_action) script. I find myself in need to perform some cleanup, either when my extension becomes inactive or when it activates, so that each subsequent use starts with "clean state" for the user.

Is it possible with current Chrome extension APIs? If yes, where should I look? `chrome.runtime` appeared to be obvious place for such functionality, but upon checking the only candidate there, [onSuspend() event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onSuspend), it didn't do what I wanted (namely, the activation/deactivation of page_action extension doesn't seem to trigger it).

Comment: There's no dedicated functionality for that. Depending on what specifically you want do, a background script + messaging may be used, or nothing at all - because the page action execution context is automatically destroyed when hidden you can simply do the cleanup at the start of the page script as it runs every time the page action is shown.

Comment: Execution context may be destroyed, but apparently the only way to store data within the context - even a transient one - is to use `chrome.storage` API, which of course stays persistent.

Comment: I tried using execution context for this data (that is, simply a variable in `default_popup` script, but it doesn't fit my use case - the context is recreated each time popup appears, not when extension goes active/inactive. I need the data to be bound to extension lifecycle, not to popup, but still to be able to use it in the popup.

Comment: Eh? The execution context is destroyed when the popup is hidden and created anew - not restored! - when it's shown. It's like any page being opened/closed in a tab. And chrome.storage isn't part of the context so it persists. I still don't know what specifically you want to do so I can't help further.

Comment: Make sure to look at a persistent background script + messaging which I already suggested. That and chrome.storage (or localStorage) are your only options anyway.